# CodeIgniter: How to return all data in the tables row after valitdaion?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this public function in the model folder that get inputs from a controller of a username and a password:

```
// Validate that the user is registered and returns true or false. 
public function validate($email, $password) {

    $this->db->select('u_email', 'u_password');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('u_email', $email);
    $this->db->where('u_password', $password);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() == 1 ) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }


}
```

I want it to return all row information that belong to this username+password (there is a u_id, u_email, u_name, u_permissions).

So I can use in the controller and save in a session:

```
    $this->load->model('membership_model'); 
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate($email, $password);


    if ( $query ) {  // if the user's credentials validated...

        $data = array(
                'u_id'  => $query->u_id,
                'email' => $query->u_email, 
                'name'  => $query->u_name,
                'permittions' => $query->u_permittion,
                'is_logged_in' => TRUE
            );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `*` to fetch all data and use `row()` to get single fetch row

```
$this->db->select('*');// use * here
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('u_email', $email);
$this->db->where('u_password', $password);

$query = $this->db->get();

if ( $query->num_rows() == 1 ) {
    return $query->row();// use row();
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html